# Where to put Extra Laravel Routes that I used once but I want to keep them only for reference

Tags: laravel, eloquent, routes

I have gone through these cases:

- I need to modify something in the database using Eloquent models, so I create a route for it then when I am done I still don't feel like deleting this code of multiple lines.
- Or I need to run this code to try and see if it works, so I create a route for it and run it then I don't know if I would need it again.

And other cases. So my question is I need to keep those routes for reference only, where should I put them?

Is there a known logical place programmers use to put experimental routes that I am not using anymore but I might need to look at them again?

Comment: Maybe make a `.txt` file and put the extra routes in there, or comment those routes.

Comment: I comment them. But as a programmer imagine going into someone else's laravel project to see his web.php file full of big comments of old routes. Not the way to leave them there.

Comment: Add `frontend_routes.php` file and add your routes there and add     `require __DIR__.'/frontend_routes.php;` in your `web.php`

Comment: @DhananjayKyada Other developers will also look at it and find that it is not useful at all. The file will be linked directly in the `web.php` file. That says this file is important for the project, but actually it is just my preferences

Comment: better practice is to use artisan commands for one offs for security purposes instead of making a oneoff routes. then you can store these in app/Console/Commands/OneOffs

Comment: @ParkerDell Is it easy to copy the route to a one off command so that I can store it if I need to look at it again ? as a reference?

Comment: you can just put the one offs routes in your readme of the code project (if its a private repository) and leave notes on what they were for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better practice is to use artisan commands for one-offs for security purposes instead of making a one-off route. Then you can store these in app/Console/Commands/OneOffs and run your commands through your console verses hitting an actual web or api route .

Like so:

`php artisan oneoffs:updateSomething --param1=1 --param2=2`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#generating-commands

Comment: Artisan commands are very good alternative to one-off routes. I can even store it in `routes/console.php`

Answer (score 1):

If you really think you need to keep these routes separated from other routes, one way of doing it is to create new `experimental.php` route inside your routes directory. After you created the file, go to `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` and register your new routes file, so that Laravel builds them automatically. First create new method to reference your experimental routes:

```
protected function mapExperimentalRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/experimental.php'));
    }
```

After that, inside the `map()` method, add this line:

```
$this->mapExperimentalRoutes();
```

Like this:

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapExperimentalRoutes();
}
```

*NOTE*: Don't forget to clear your `cache` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: The routes we are talking about are not that big a deal to leave them accessible through the `RouteServiceProvider`

Comment: Registering routes in `RouteServiceProvider` is just done for convenience, so you don't have to manually load them somewhere else when you need them. The new experimental routes will be accessible like any other route you have inside `routes.php` file, but they will be separated in another file.

Comment: Yes another file. That is a way to do it. Did you have to do it one day? did you try it yourself?

Comment: Actually yes, but for a different purpose. I was creating a new package for file uploads that I intended to use for multiple projects. All the package files were separated in custom directory, including the routes files. In order to use those routes, I did these steps above, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can create one middleware,where you check if the execution happened from your ip. and you can protect your routes with that middleware.

Comment: Yes, but the question is specifically about what is the common place developers use to put their extra routes only for reference?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy yes,but putting them without middleware may cause security issue.as anyone can execute them.